# SQL query processing order: Group By first or Join First?

Tags: sql

I need to execute an SQL query.
If i have a query with multiple tables in From clause with Join condition in Where clause,
And i have Group by statement,
Should i perform Join operation first followed by Group By ?
OR should i perform Group By first then Join ?
Which one would be better ?

Note: In my environment, whichever operator that filters out more tuples should be executed first for better performance and less usage of memory for overall query execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DB's EXPLAIN syntax, You'll see witch of this two methods (in Yours specific environment) will cause more DB operations taken to produce output

Comment: I used like Explain Select * from Test
I am unable to understand the Output of this query.
Is there any good link to understand it ?